# Proper Linear Subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space.  I want to prove that for any proper linear subspace $M$, there exists a point $x$ with $||x||=1$ such that $inf\{||x-y||:y\in M\}>1-\epsilon$ for arbitrary epsilon.  Could anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean $>1-\epsilon$? Otherwise you can just take $x\in M$. Or maybe you specifically want to find an $x$ not lying in $M$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  I meant greater than not less than.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is well known [Riesz lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma). For the proof see [this notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/riesz_lemma.pdf).